Why the results of dtreeviz visualization are not equivalent to the features given by decision tree feature importance
When I used dtreeviz to visualize a decision tree, I found that the order of importance of feature variables given by the decision tree was 1-2-3-4-5, and the visualized decision tree 1 was the root node. However, the order given by dtreeviz drawing was 2-3-4-5, without root node 1, and instead 2 was used as the root node.
Why does this happen? Is this phenomenon normal? How should I explain that 1 is the most important feature in feature importance, while 2 is the most important feature as the root node in the drawing?
The source data has 32 features.
The first idea is that after calculating the feature importance, I use dtreeviz to draw a plot to compare whether the two features are the same. The two are different.
The second idea is that after calculating the feature importance, I extract the top 5 features separately and use dtreeviz to draw a plot to compare the features. The two are different.
Has anyone encountered this situation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
